# Free vs. Paid: Picking a Financial Model

Tags: monetization

I finally embarked upon my first "paid" game. What this means is that I will incorporate [some sort of monetization strategy](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4968/what-revenue-models-exist-for-online-games?rq=1) in my game. This may mean making the app pay-to-download, making it "freemium" with paid content, or something else.

Having never done something like this, I'm at a complete loss as to how to figure out what I should do. I know a couple of models (pay to download, freemium, etc.) and I can brainstorm some ideas. But how do I figure out what strategy to use?

Perhaps there's some body of research on this? (I recall reading that MMOs popular in Korea use a model where cosmetic changes only are pay-to-buy; everything else is free).

Comment: As far as which one to use, seems like that's entirely up to you. Are you more asking what financial models are available to choose from?

Comment: @Byte56 no, that's already defined well in another question on this site. Given all the models, I'm asking: how do I figure out which one to apply to my game?

Comment: You might try this question over at http://answers.onstartups.com. Maybe someone over there can help you find a way to make this decision.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how that's different from asking "How do I figure out what kind of game to make?" It's totally up to what you want to do. It can't really be answered by someone else.

So it's like any other difficult choice, list out your choices and write down what you think are the pros (with a positive score) and cons (with a negative score). Sum the total scores for each item, then go with the item with the highest score. However, I imagine you'll figure out which one you want before you even get to that point.

Comment: Not a bad approach. I'll try that.